# How can I create a recursive sum of differences?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to implement a recursive sum of differences - that probably makes little sense. So basically I am keeping track of a vehicle mileages and on a separate tab (sheet) I wish to see the progress in mileage.

[image]

So, let's say, I wish to immediately find out how many miles I traveled on July 8th during day (so 151223-151080) and during the night (so 151308-150855151223), and so on. How could I implement that?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I have edited the question to show how you came to these numbers because that really was not immediately clear; please check if my assumptions are correct. Also, the fact that several people need to have access seems to irrelevant - I suggest you edit it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume the mileage data is in column C on sheet3.

Then in the cell where you want the answer to appear use the formula

```
=max(Sheet3!C:C)-min(Sheet3!C:C)
```

Comment: awesome! simple yet elegant ... but what if things are slightly more complex?